# curl command to grep output and validate using bash script

Tags: bash, curl, grep

I am trying to run a curl command , grep the output and need to validate the output against

I tried this way , but I am stuck between grepping the output so that I can validate.

```
    curl -Is ${1} | grep -Fi "url"  &> /dev/null
    if [[ "grep out put should be here"  && "$a" != "123" ]]; then
        echo "File exist on $ENV_NAME"
    else
        echo "ERROR"
        return 1
    fi
    echo_done
```

I am unable to fetch the grep output and use it in the if statement. 
Appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending your grep output to a variable using command substitution:

```
grepout=$(curl -Is ${1} | grep -Fi "url")
if [[ "$grepout" && "$a" != "123" ]]
then
  echo "file exists"
else
  echo "ERROR"
  return 1
fi
```

Something along those lines should work.